# How to get the latitude and longitude value based on the location address in core java?

Tags: java, dictionary, google-api, latitude-longitude

Need to get Latitude and Longitude on the basis of location.

I am trying to write a method like that takes the **input as the address** and **returns** the result as **latitude and longitude value** in core java, so I'm looking for the API's by which I can achieve this.

Here's an example

```
public double getLatLongValue("newyork")
{
 . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . 
return latlongval;

}
```

It will give output as

Latitude : 40.712784

Longitude : -74.005941

So, far I've checked this website http://www.latlong.net/.
I want to implement such type of thing in core java, so which are the core classes or methods in API I should focus on!.

Comment: it's called ***Google Maps*** API.

Comment: You should just check google api, I guess it will solve your issue. And here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating class like:

```
class LocationInfo {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    //getter setter
}
public LocationInfo getLatLongValue(String address) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I do not think that this is what the OP is after...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something such as [`Nominatim`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), which is a freely available [geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) service.

Your method would just need to hit a particular URL and then process the response.

Once processed, you can then use a custom class to wrap the result so that you get what you are after.